# Recovering a swap partition

Tags: partitioning, dd, swap

I accidentally wrote data to my swap partition using `dd`. Both the swap partition and the intended medium for writing to are 16GB in size, and I got confused.

My PC seems unable to use the swap partition now. How can I recover this? I still have the partition, with the size it should have. It's `/dev/sda4` where I do want to keep `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to use `mkswap`:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sda4
```

Here `sda4` is your swap partition device.

Then use `swapon` to activate it:

```
sudo swapon /dev/sda4
```

If `/etc/fstab` still has the swap entry, then the swap partition will be retained after a reboot.

Everything you need to know about swapping is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq). It's an Ubuntu site, but the information should be valid for other distributions.